# R: Moving parameter time series filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to create a time-varying recursive filter.

The classical filter that is implemented in [`stats::filter`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/filter.html) has the form:

> Y[t] = X[t] + b[1](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/filter.html)*Y[t-1] + b[2]*Y[t-2] + ....

However, I want to create a filter that varies by the day-of-the-week that `t` happens to be, so:

> Y[t] = X[t] + b[day_of_week(t), 1]*Y[t-1] + b[day_of_week(t), 2]*Y[t-2] + ...

As an additional complication not supported by `stats::filter`, I also need to have a coefficient modulating the first term:

> Y[t] = b[day_of_week(t), 0]*X[t] + b[day_of_week(t), 1]*Y[t-1] + b[day_of_week(t), 2]*Y[t-2] + ...

---

Here is an example dataset that illustrates the need:

```
library(dplyr)

parameters = matrix(data = runif(14), nrow = 7, ncol = 2, 
                    dimnames = list(c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), 
                                    c("same_day_impact", "previous_day_impact")))

df_x = data_frame(date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2015-01-01"), 
                                  to = as.Date("2015-12-31"), 
                                  by = "day")) %>% 
                  mutate(series = rnorm(n()),
                         series_lag = lag(series, 1, default = 0),
                         day_of_week = wday(date),
                         day_of_week_name = wday(date, label = TRUE),
                         same_day_impact = parameters[day_of_week, 1],
                         previous_day_impact = parameters[day_of_week, 2])
```

So, I want, `same_day_impact*series + previous_day_impact*.`, where the `.` indicates the result of the filter up to the previous time point.

I am essentially looking for a neat way to achieve this. Any help is welcome.

Comment: what corresponds to `X` in your dataframe? series? series_lag is `X[t-1]` ?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel That is correct.

Comment: so you want to have the result of `same_day_impact*X[t]+ previous_day_impact*Y[t-1]` ?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Correct.

Comment: `b[..,2]` correspond to previous_day_impact ? b should be a matrix according to your formula with 7 rows and theoretically unlimited number of columns. But does it mean you want to go backward only up to `2` ?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel The first column is the same day impact (on `X[t]`) and the second column is the impact of the value of the filter in the previous period (on `Y[t-1]`).